# Qual o padrão de projeto a ser usado para salvar objetos que tem formas de salvar parecidas?

Tags: java-ee, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Estou com essa dúvida pois se não me engano já li, vi, ou até mesmo implementei algo desse tipo mas não estou mais lembrando, é o seguinte:

Tenho aqui um projeto EJB com várias entidades, algumas delas tem formas muito parecidas de salvar como por exemplo a entidade Contrato e AuxilioFinanceiro, estas duas (e mais outras) vão implementar uma lista de Competencias e salvar outros atributos básicos. A questão é que para que eu não tenha que implementar vários Services e vários DAOs com os mesmos métodos salvar mudando uma coisinha aqui ou acolá acho que eu poderia ter algo como um service ou dao   genérico que pegava o objeto de qualquer entidade e a própria entidade se encarregava de se salvar.

Tentamos fazer com uma Factory que cria o dao correspondente ao tipo do objeto repassado mas acho que ainda não é por aí... Não sei ao certo mas talvez até usando injeção de dependência seria bem mais elegante... Alguém podia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Você está usando `JPA`? Se sim o `EntityManager` pode ser utilizado para persistir qualquer entidade. Enquanto, por questões arquiteturais é interessante centralizar os acessos a banco, [DAOs certamente não são um requisito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818589/java-ee-architecture-are-daos-still-recommended-when-using-an-orm-like-jpa-2). Se você quiser adotar um padrão recomendo o [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/), com ele você basicamente vai apenas declarar interfaces estendendo `CrudRepository` no caso básico, ele faz todo o resto para você.

Comment: Sim @Anthony Accioly, estou usando JPA. Sei que o EntityManager é capaz de salvar qualquer entidade mas terei que criar o DAO de cada entidade, certo? Vou dar uma olhada no Spring Data JPA para ver se abrange o desejado...

Comment: Vinícius, não necessáriamente. O DAO é um padrão como todos; você pode obter o Entity Manager onde quiser (na sua camada de domínio - rico - por exemplo, ou diretamente na camada de serviços, caso isolar acessos ao banco não for uma prioridade). Pessoalmente gosto de ter uma camada de DAOs ou Repositórios para centralizar acesso, mas isso não é, de maneira alguma, um requisito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desconheço um *padrão de projeto* que faça isso diretamente. Contudo, existem várias técnicas para se alcançar este objetivo.

## Programação Orientada a Aspectos (AOP)

O projeto Spring Data JPA, citado pelo @AnthonyAccioly, é um exemplo de uso de AOP. Ele permite a "geração" automática de Repositórios para interface com o banco de dados com base em interfaces.

Basicamente, você declara uma interface que estende a interface `JPARepository` do Spring. Pronto, o Spring faz o resto.

Por [exemplo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.M1/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html):

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);

  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

Somente através das assinaturas acima o Spring será capaz de prover a implementação dos métodos e injetar um *bean* concreto onde você precisar.

Além disso, a interface `JPARepository` já vem com vários métodos básicos para CRUDs.

Note que [*Repository* é o nome de um padrão de projeto](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Ele é análogo ao DAO, a diferença é que a interface do DAO segue o padrão de um banco de dados enquanto o Repository segue o padrão de uma *Coleção*.

## [Genéricos (Generics)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Este recurso da linguagem Java é excelente para este tipo de tarefa. Se existem várias classes que são usadas em operações praticamente iguais e não é possível ou não é desejável usar polimorfismo para isso, basta declarar uma classe que executa essas operações com o tipo parametrizado.

Não vou detalhar a implementação aqui, porque seria uma resposta extremamente longa. Mas basta pesquisar um pouco para encontrar [algumas](https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) [implementações](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-genericdao/) já existentes.